# How can I override a value at its id from a dropdown?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to write a script to put data in specific lines based on the id.
I already have that:

```
 function copy(){ 

  var tabelle1=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var tabelle2=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet2 ");

  tabelle2.getRange(3,7).copyTo(tabelle1.getRange(tabelle1.getLastRow()+1,1));
  tabelle2.getRange(13,4).copyTo(tabelle1.getRange(tabelle1.getLastRow()+0,2));
}
```

[image for the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8CEL.png)

Now my question is how can I delete all lines with the same id (1) before copying the lines with the script. (See picture)
Or if my list has each id only once, how can I override the value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should do it. Your code was incorrect in its sheet references. I used setValue instead of copyTo since you need the value selected to pass to the readRows function it just seems cleaner.

```
function copy(){ 
  var tabelle1=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var tabelle2=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  var sel=tabelle1.getRange(3,7).getValue()
   readRows(sel)
  tabelle2.getRange(tabelle2.getLastRow()+1,1).setValue(sel);
  var tm=tabelle1.getRange(13,4).getValue()
  tabelle2.getRange(tabelle2.getLastRow()+0,2).setValue(tm);
}
function readRows(sel) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  var lr=sheet.getLastRow()
  var values = sheet.getRange(1,1,lr,2).getValues();
  var rowsDeleted = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i <= values.length-1; i++) {
     var row = values[i][0];
     if (row == sel) {
      sheet.deleteRow((parseInt(i)+1) - rowsDeleted);
      rowsDeleted++;
    }
  }
};
```